# What are the differences between 效果 and 效应?

Tags: meaning, difference

Which of the following sentences is correct, or are both correct? Why?

1. 虽然学校采取了一些措施，但是没有什么效果.
2. 虽然学校采取了一些措施，但是没有什么效应.

Answer (score 3):

效果: result; effect

效应: effect

> 1.虽然学校采取了一些措施，但是没有什么效果. 2.虽然学校采取了一些措施，但是没有什么效应.

Both 没有效果 and 没有效应 are correct if you want to say "no effect"

When you want to say "result" then you must say "效果"

Example:

"US tax reform has not **achieved** the expected **results**" = "美国税改并未**达到**预期的**效果**"

"US tax reform has not **created** the expected **effect**" = "美国税改并未**产生**预期的**效应**"

Since 效果 has meaning other than 'effect' We usually translate 'effect' as 效应

As user 3306356's answer stated:   'the butterfly effect' is translated as 蝴蝶效应 (the butterfly effect) instead of 蝴蝶效果(the butterfly effect/result)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference is in the fact that **效应** is, usually, effect, as in: [the butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect), [the Matthew effect,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect) [the Bambi effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bambi_effect) or as [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_effects) explains it:

> observable phenomena

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you meant. 效果 can also be observable.

Answer (score 0):

虽然学校采取了一些措施，但是没有什么效应.
This sentence is wrong.

效果means result, but 效应 emphasize effect and influences.